# Select records where not exist in relational table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to return all Tickets which have no rows in the assigns table + all records that have same user id.
but an error keeps coming up. Probably due to my newness to laravel.

**Relation Model**

```
class Ticket extends Model
{
    public function AssignedUsers() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'assigns','ticket_id','user_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

**here is the code:**

```
$tickets = Ticket::with('AssignedUsers')
        ->WhereHas('AssignedUsers', function($q) {
            $q->where('assigns.user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
            ->orWhere('assigns.ticket_id','!=','tickets.id');
        })
        ->get();
```

so far I can fetch all records with same user_id, however adding the no rows condition seems to be the issue, and I'm not sure if I'm even approaching it the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean this:

```
$tickets = Ticket::with('AssignedUsers')
    ->whereHas('AssignedUsers', function($q) {
        $q->where('assigns.user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
    })
    ->orDoesntHave('AssignedUsers')
    ->get();
```